# Telegram Bot, answer in private chat

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm setting up a Telegram Bot, everything works fine but now i would like the bot to answer in private chat for a specific command which was asked in a group. I used Python 3.x.

How can I get the Chat ID of the Private Chat between the Bot and the user?

Answer (score 3):

Telegram API names it as `chat_id`. You can send message to `chat_id` which goes to private chat.

Keep in mind that bots can't start a conversation(chat dialog, private chat), unless a user starts it first.

Comment: But if i make `chat_id=update.message.chat_id` the bot answers in the group Chat

Comment: If your bot doesn't have any private conversation with a particular user, then you can't send a message to them.

Comment: I know but if there was a conversation with the user, how can I get the chat_id

Comment: @WlanWerner get the chat_id of the conversation, that's it.

Comment: @RamazanPolat Is there any way to find out if there has been previous contact? (other than to log every convo?)

Comment: @Kraay89, you don't log convos, Telegram already has your convos. First you get dialogs. Each dialog has participant chat_ids. If you don't have any dialog, then you can't get their chat_id, therefore can't talk with them.

Answer (score 2):

The [Update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) contains a message, that tells you who sent it. 
The `chat_id` of the user is equal to the `id` of the [User](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) object.

You can retrieve it as following:

```
chat_id = update.message.from.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to answer a user in pm (switch from group to pm)...

Use : `text = "http://telegram.me/<Bot_Username>?start=start"`

replace '*<Bot_Username>*' with *your bots username (dont include the "<>") ,

eg: " http://telegram.me/jesvi_bot?start=start " would take me straight to my bot's pm

send this as a reply text/link in the target group & upon the target user clicking it, it would re direct them to the bots private message..

So a full Example would be :

```
update.message.reply_text(text="http://telegram.me/jesvi_bot?start=start")
```

where 'jesvi_bot' in this case refers to my bot's username & replace it with your bot's username.

Comment: Can you show an example using ForceReply?

Comment: updated the comment, use "http://telegram.me/<Bot_Username>?start=start" to switch to  private message on click

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at this piece of code:

```py
def bot_func(update, context):

    update.message.reply_text(text='chunk',
                              parse_mode='HTML')

    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.from_user.id,
                             text='chunk',
                             parse_mode='HTML')
```

The first method will reply in current chat and simply accept the `chat_id` as is, regardless whether the `chat_id` belongs to a private chat or a group chat:

```py
    update.message.reply_text(text='chunk',
                              parse_mode='HTML')
```

##### Force Reply as a private chat

The second method will **force reply as a private chat**, as the message is directy send to the user specified in `update.message.from_user.id`:

```py
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.from_user.id,
                             text='chunk',
                             parse_mode='HTML')
```